# Word template: command button runs wrong macro

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

(Office 365 ProPlus version 1701 build 7766.2099, running on Windows 7)

(Edited post, original is lower.)
ActiveX command buttons that occur in a template in a different order than they were created can call the wrong macro, when a file is created from that template.

Exact steps to reproduce:
Create a new document. Save it as a .dotm file. Press enter a couple times to create space at the top of the document. Create an ActiveX Command Button. Double-click it to create procedure, put in MsgBox to ID it. Create a second button ABOVE the first, and its procedure. Now, when the buttons are clicked in the template, they work fine (top one reports 2, bottom reports 1), but when clicked in a file created from the template (double-click file in Explorer window), they are swapped (top reports 1, bottom reports 2).

(Original)
A very long time ago (earlier version of Word), I created a Word template (.dotm) with buttons that run macros. It used to work fine. I've recently discovered that the buttons now call the wrong macros. If I double-click the template file (creating a new file based on the template), the first button calls the third button's macro and vice-versa. (Middle button, "Fill out forms", works fine.) If I right-click the template and choose Open (open the template itself, not create a new file), the buttons work as designed.

I've boiled the template down to just the 3 buttons and their macros (see photos), and am still seeing the same issue. Clicking "Reset fields", which should call ResetFieldsButton_Click(), instead runs MyPrintButton_Click(). (I get the "Printing..." popup.) What's going on?
[image: buttons]
[image]

Comment: The same document of course - I'm obviously tired. I'd try recreating the buttons in the template (copy of the template) with new names, see if that works. If not, try recreating the template. If that still doesn't work I'd try MacroButton fields instead of ActiveX controls.

Comment: I verified the exact same behavior in a new template created for the purpose - create 3 ActiveX buttons, create their macros, then cut the third one and paste it into the document before the first one.

On a related note, I tried removing the original 3 buttons and replacing them with 3 new ones, carefully keeping them in the correct order, and setting up new subs for them to call. As before, everything works fine when clicking them in the template - but now a new document doesn't react at all when they're clicked.

Comment: Ugh. Sounds like a problem in the new version. I'll test it tomorrow and see if I can replicate it

Comment: My test: New file; insert some text; insert three ActiveX command buttons; double-click each button in turn and add a MsgBox line of code; turn off Design Mode; click each button. Worked fine. Save As *.dotm and close. Create a new doc from the template, test the buttons. They work correctly. Is it possible you copy/pasted the CommandButton controls instead of insert new ones each time? Version 1708 by the way, updated semi-annually.

Comment: Cindy, to get mine to fail, I selected and "cut" the third button, then pasted it above the first one in the document - so they were no longer in the order that they were created. I suspect the sequence they're in the document is what makes the difference - despite having the correct names.

Comment: Actually, it's probably more the fact that you cut and pasted. That destroys the button, which cuts its link to the macro. So if you create all new buttons, double-click them to generate a procedure, then copy/paste the code into the procedures - does it then work?

Comment: Verified again - same issue, without cut-and-paste. Exact steps to reproduce: Create a new document. Save it as a .dotm file. Create 3 ActiveX Command Buttons. Double-click each to create procedure, put in MsgBox to ID them. Drag the third one to the top of the document, so new order is 3-1-2 Save. Now, when the buttons are clicked in the template: they work fine (3-1-2), but when clicked in a file created from the template, two are swapped (2-1-3).

Comment: Dragging is no different than cut-and-paste, under the covers. Quite simply: *don't do that*. If you need to change the order, delete and insert a new one.

Comment: The core of the bug is this - when pressed, the macro called by the button ("name" + _Click)isn't the macro that all documentation says should be called, but only for files created from the template. Why?

And both dragging and cut-and-paste are red herrings. I tried again from scratch, this time simply creating the third button at the top of the document. Same thing - they call the wrong macro!

Comment: I still can't repro - it doesn't matter where or in what order I insert them. Try renaming your Normal.dotm  then start Word. Word will create a "clean" copy of the default template it uses to create new documents. See if it still happens in a template you create from that.

Comment: Renamed Normal.dotm, verified a new one was created. Tried again from scratch - same issue. I'm going to edit the problem description to use the extremely-boiled-down example, for clarity.